# Trivial Questions Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular vectors and $\left\|x\right\|=2$ and $\left\|y\right\|=1$, why isn't $\left\|x+y\right\|$ simply $3$?

Would $\left\|x+y\right\|$ form the diagonal of the rectangle, and we use the Pythagorean theorem to solve?

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand the rationale for this question. The Pythagorean theorem does **not** state that a right triangle with side lengths $2$ and $1$ has hypotenuse length $2+1$... so why expect that here?

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \neq a+b$

Answer (score 6):

As you said, use pythagoras theorem.
$$\|x+y\|^2=\langle x+y, x+y\rangle=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2\langle x, y \rangle =\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$$

We shouldn't expect it to be equal to $3$.

Comment: why do we use ||x+y||^2 to solve for ||x+y||? Or do we just take square the root of ||x||^2 + ||y||^2

Comment: Because we know the relationship that $\|z\|^2 = \langle z,z \rangle$ and using inner product enables us to use the property that $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular. $$\|x+y\|=\sqrt{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2}$$